# How can I substract two FILETIMEs?

Tags: c++, windows

I'm trying to get the elapsed times in miliseconds in windows. The only way I've found to do this is to get the number of 100 nanoseconds since 1601 with the FILETIME structure. But the FILETIME structure stores the value in two variables, and I want to know how I can substract two of this structures, divide them by 10000 (to get the miliseconds) and store the result in a single variable
I'm using c++ with visual studio 2008 express edition

Comment: Programming language? Framework?

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought I had put it. I'm using c++ with visual studio 2008 express edition

Comment: IMO this is a perfectly legitimite question and answer as currently worded. It should be reopened.

Comment: This question should be reopened.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read the documentation of [`FILETIME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724284%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> It is not recommended that you add and subtract values from the **FILETIME** structure to obtain relative times. Instead, you should copy the low- and high-order parts of the file time to a [ULARGE_INTEGER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383742%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure, perform 64-bit arithmetic on the **QuadPart** member, and copy the **LowPart** and **HighPart** members into the **FILETIME** structure.

And there you have your single number, too (`QuadPart` of the `ULARGE_INTEGER` structure).

Comment: Ok thank you, that solved the problem. But it says that QuadPart only can be used if the compiler suports built in 64 bit integers. Visual studio supports it, but when I make the executable will it work in any system with windows installed?

Comment: The executable itself by definition doesn't depend on the compiler anymore.

Comment: But I mean, even if it is running in a 32 bit machine?. I have no idea if this matters

Comment: It doesn't. The address width of a CPU or the OS doesn't have anything to do with whether it's capable of doing arithmetic with larger numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
FILETIME ft1;
FILETIME ft2;

int iDifferenceInMS = (*((ULONGLONG*)&ft2) - *((ULONGLONG*)&ft1))/10000;
```

Comment: This actually can be very bad. FILETIMES are 32-bit aligned, not 64-bit aligned. This means that, depending on where the compiler put the variable in memory, and depending on the system. This means can crash when run on certain machines. You do not want this sadness.

On the other hand, a ULARGE_INTEGER is required to be 64-bit aligned, so you will not get these alignment faults.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that I have been using for a long time.
m_ft is a member variable of type FILETIME
CMyTimeSpan is a class that basically carries a LARGE_INTEGER.
This effectively gives you want. MyTimeSpan only handles differences of up to 32 bits but should not be an issue if you actually need the entire 64, and handle the return value appropriately.

```
CMyTimeSpan CMyTime::operator-(const CMyTime& rh) const
{
   ULARGE_INTEGER  left, right;
   LARGE_INTEGER    dif;
   // convert filetimes to ULARGE_INTEGER
   left.LowPart     = m_ft.dwLowDateTime;
   left.HighPart    = m_ft.dwHighDateTime;
   right.LowPart    = rh.m_ft.dwLowDateTime;
   right.HighPart   = rh.m_ft.dwHighDateTime;
   
   dif.QuadPart = left.QuadPart - right.QuadPart;
   CMyTimeSpan rv(dif);
   return rv;
}
```